# How to list files installed by a given Windows Installer?

Tags: windows-installer

I'd like to be able to examine an application installer and find out what files it will install.  For bonus points: I'd like to be able to extract files into a directory of my own choosing rather than running the installer.  If neither is possible, I'd settle for being able to obtain the list of installed files after installation.

In the linux world of .deb (Debian) and .rpm packages, I can list the contents of any package installed using a tool such as "dpkg" or "rpm".  I can even probe the package file itself and get the list prior to installing the package.  What is the equivalent mechanism in Windows XP?

Answer (score 2):

While it's possible to extract the files from a .MSI package without running it through custom code, it's easier still to run an administrative install (`msiexec /a package.msi`). This will extract its files into a format that can then be used to perform an install, or just allow you to examine its contents.

Answer (score -1):

`msiexec` allows to log installation with /L option.
You can log everything that happens during installation with `/L*V.

`c:\Users\Dmytro_Poliarush\Downloads>msiexec /i package.msi /L*V inst.log`
It is more convenient to name file with `.txt` extension so you can see it when opening with notepad.

See more in `msiexec /?` and [here](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/qa-log.html)

Answer (score -2):

You can try 3rd party uninstaller software which will monitors the installation process and log the changes, files/registries etc. E.g. http://www.martau.com/

Comment: One software is removed from the internet because they bank corrupt. But i paid my license. How can i before uninstall, copy the whole files of that package?